# JQuery SetInterval no Working

Tags: jquery

I have following JQuery code. I trying to get the click to reset the setInterval so the timer starts again. eg: resets to 5 seconds. So if its counted 4 seconds and I click it should reset to a new full 5 seconds.

```
var varTimerSpeed = 5000;
bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval();
function bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval() {
    var varTimerInterval = setInterval(function () {
        bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdate();
    }, varTimerSpeed);
}


$('#mainBannerOurTopSuggestionsIMG').click(function() {
    clearInterval(varTimerInterval);
    bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval();
});
```

I can see the click event is working (by writing to console) however it doesn't appear the reset the setInterval. Is there something I'm missing here?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var varTimerSpeed = 5000;
var varTimerInterval;

function bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval() {
    varTimerInterval = setInterval(function () {
        bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdate();
    }, varTimerSpeed);
}


$('#mainBannerOurTopSuggestionsIMG').click(function() {
    if( typeof(varTimerInterval) != 'undefined')
        clearInterval(varTimerInterval);
    bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval();
});
bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval();
```

try it?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the scope of the variable `varTimerInterval`, you have declared it to be a local variable in the `bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval` method, so it will not be available in the `click` handler.

Since you need to access the same variable `varTimerInterval` in 2 different methods, you need to declare it in a scope shared by both of those functions so that both of the will access the same instance.

```
var varTimerSpeed = 5000,
    varTimerInterval;
bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval();

function bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval() {
    varTimerInterval = setInterval(function () {
        bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdate();
    }, varTimerSpeed);
}


$('#mainBannerOurTopSuggestionsIMG').click(function () {
    clearInterval(varTimerInterval);
    bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

var varTimerInterval is locally scoped to the bannerDisplayMembersMatchingCriteriaUpdateTimerInterval function.

try declaring it above as you did with varTimerSpeed;